# Returning async callback as best practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

So far I've never returned any async callbacks, I've just called them. I was not aware (stupid me!) that the code after the callback call is executed as well.

This shows what I mean:

```
var asyncFunctionNoReturn = function(callback) {
    alert('Inside asyncFunctionNoReturn');
    callback();
    alert('Still inside asyncFunctionNoReturn');
};

var asyncFunctionReturn = function(callback) {
    alert('Inside asyncFunctionReturn');
    return callback();
    alert('You will never see me! :(');
};

asyncFunctionNoReturn(function() {
    alert('I am called back!');
});

asyncFunctionReturn(function() {
    alert('I am called back!');
});
```

To me this is only relevant if there is code after the callback-call:

Version 1:

```
...
if(err) {
    callback(err);
} else {
    callback(null, data);
}
```

Version 2:

```
...
if(err) return callback(err);
return callback(null, data);
```

I've seen both versions used. Which one has been established as "best practice"?

My guess would be version 2:

- Less code and less nesting (-> better readability?)
- Can be extended better

I hope this is not too opinion-based.

Comment: I do not completely agree with `less code and less nesting -> better readability`, for example I find more readable Version 1. I find sometimes one-line-if-else hard to read rapidly. sorry for the little OT

Comment: This is primary opinion-based. Beside they have a different meaning cause of the `return`, Personally to me Version 1 is better readable and I like it better as I could insert some debug/logging information right before `callback(err);` if something is wrong at that place. But how it this related to the first part of your question, where you return a callback that will prevent the following code from being executed?

Comment: Ok. I agree with you. The brackets improve readability so version 1 is better about this. @t.niese In version 1 is don't return the callback. My primary intenton was to ask if this is a bad practice and should always be avoided.

Comment: Returning something from an async function (except for chaining)  is uncommon and can be considered as bad practice. The only common pattern in js where something is returned from an async call is to support: `asyncCall(callback)` and `asyncCall().on('error',errorCallback).on('end',endCallback').on('result',resultCallback)`  or for Promise/A+ `obj.doAsync().then(resultCallback)`

Comment: I don't talk about returning something, but "return" the callback call as I do in version 2. What's the problem with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I don't always agree with Douglas Crockford (OMG, what have I said? ;-) ), but I think he is right about `if` statement: it should always be written with brackets (http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html).

And I don't agree with you: less code does not mean better readability, and for me, the first version is much more obvious about the intent of the code. Let the (amazing) tools we have nowadays to worry about minifying/uglifying the code for production.

Still, you could (should?) return the result of the callbacks anyway.

So I would write:

```
if (err) {
    return callback(err);
} else {
    return callback(null, data);
}
```

Comment: Yes, to me this makes sense. It's better readable and avoids code execution after the call back.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the environment and framework you have different convention.

With js in *node.js* and also with the browser the common convention about async are:

- a regular async function takes a optional callback as last parameter
- the callback has to look like `callback( err, args1, ...)` having `err` and no arguments in the case of an error, and `err` null and optional arguments in when success.
- the callback has to be call **always** async.
- The async functions of a library/module should **all** behave the same or their behavior should be determined by their naming `doSomething`, `doSomethingSync`, `doSomethingAsync`

So if you return something from a async function you should do the same for all of your async functions in your module. Ideally using an existing convention like returning an EventEmitter or a Promise.

Generally things are considered as bad practice if the behavior is not expected.